# Show a form while BackgroundWorker is running

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I want to display a "loading form" (a form with some text message plus a progressBar with style set to marquee) while the `BackgroundWorker`'s job isn't done. When the `BackgroundWorker` is done, the loading form must be closed automatically. Although I do use a `BackgroundWorker`, the main thread should wait until it's done. I was able to do that using a [`AutoResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd6a283y(v=vs.110).aspx) but I noticied that as it does block the main thread, the form loading's progressBar is freezed too.

My question is: How can I show that form without freeze it while runing a process in background and wait for it finish? I hope it's clear.

Here's my current code:

```
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    //a windows form with a progressBar and a label
    loadingOperation loadingForm = new loadingOperation(statusMsg);
    //that form has a progressBar that's freezed. I want to make 
    // it not freezed.
    loadingForm.Show();

    bw.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
    {
        try
        {
            if (!e.Cancel)
            {
               //do something
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            resetEvent.Set();
        }
    };

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    resetEvent.WaitOne();
    loadingForm.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("we are done!");
```

Comment: Backgroundworker doesn't stop the main thread. You can use the events progresschanged, runworkercompleted etc if you want to do something. Just use dispatcher object to call anything of main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your `BackgroundWorker`'s `RunWorkerCompleted` to a callback that will close the form like so:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
    object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    loadingForm.Close();  
    MessageBox.Show("we are done!");
}
```

You can delete the `resetEvent.WaitOne();`

You'll need to make `loadingForm` a *field* of course.

### Tell me more

> Occurs when the background operation has completed, has been canceled, or has raised an exception

- [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I really need to wait the BackgroundWorker finish to continue to running the statements. For example, check out the edited code, `MessageBox.Show()` will be called before the `DoWork` is complete, isn't?

Comment: @Jack Please see revised answer

Comment: I've done this before. Let me try explain better. Let's assume the `BackgroundWorker` is called inside `foo()` function and I have inside `hehe()` function the following statements: `foo(); baa()`. The function `baa()` will get called before `DoWork` is complete. I know I could move `baa()` to inside `DoWork` event. But I can't, in this case. `foo()` must return only when the `backgroundWorker` is done. That's why I've used `AutoResetEvent`

Comment: @Jack Sounds like a new question perhaps?

Comment: @Jack Why the `BackgroundWorker` need to call by `foo()` but not `hehe()`?

Answer (score 0):

Make the login form object an instance variable.

```
//use RunWorkerCompleted event to get notified about work completion where you close the form.
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

event handler code:

```
private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.loadingForm.close();    
}
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've done this before. The issue is: I really need to wait the BackgroundWorker finish to continue to running the statements. For example, check out the edited code, MessageBox.Show() will be called before the DoWork is complete, isn't?

Comment: Anything that you want to do after worker finishes should be called from `bw_RunWorkerComplete` handler method which is called only after DoWork has finished.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> Cek this script, Loading is Form with PictureBox - image gif

```
private delegate void showProgressCallBack(int value);

private void btnStart5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        Loading f = new Loading();
        f.Show();

        bw.DoWork += (s, ea) =>
        {
            try
            {
                test1();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
            }
        };
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, ea) =>
        {
            f.Close();
        };

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

---

```
private void showProgress(int value)
    {
        if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            showProgressCallBack showProgressDelegate =  new showProgressCallBack(showProgress);
            this.Invoke(showProgressDelegate, new object[] {value});
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar1.Value = value;
        }
    }
```

---

```
private void test()
    {
        showProgress(20);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        showProgress(80);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        showProgress(100);
    }
```

---

[image]