# C# Backgroundworker - show form while running code and close after code finishes

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a method for Excel master-detail export that is handled in button_click. Method is runnning in 3 separate threads for faster performance. I want to show a Form that notifies user about data processing (not a progress bar form, just a form with image in It). Using backgroundworker form opens nicely without blocking UI thread, but I can't close It when I need to - after method for Excel export is finished.

1st attempt:

```
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
            alert = new process_form();
            alert.ShowDialog();
            bw.DoWork += (s, ea) =>
            {
                // Error: current thread must be set to single thread apartment(STA) mode before OLE calls can be made.

                //Method for Excel export - It runs in async
                ExportData();

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            };
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, ea) =>
            {
                //close form
                this.Invoke(new System.Action(() => { alert.Close(); }));
            };
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

2nd attempt - no errors but I can't close form:

```
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

        //Method for Excel export
        ExportData();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  }

  private void ExportData()
  {
    //...

    //Cancel async just before SaveFileDialog shows
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();

    SaveFileDialog save_export = new SaveFileDialog();
    if (save_export() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
      //...
    }
  }

  private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
            if ((backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                alert.Close();
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                alert = new process_form();
                alert.ShowDialog();
            }
    }
```

I have tried also with creating a new Thread and open a form from there, and then call Thread.Abort(), but that produces some undesired results - for instance, when process_form closes any underlying Windows window becomes top window above application. So backgroundworker is something I would like as solution.

Comment: You propably have it all Backwards by having the BGW create the Form. Instead make the Make the Form contain the BGW and have it start on Form.Show Event. Also turn the Form into a Modal Dialog. Besides the speicfic soluton for Windows Forms + BGW you say you are using Multithreading for increased Performance. But multithreading only helps with CPU bound work. How certain are you that is the case? This sounds like it would be Disk bound (the I/O of excel) first and foremost.

Comment: your background worker is showing alert as dialog, which means all processing on the form stops until alert is closed. Your dowork therefore checks its not cancelling and shows a dialog.. it no longer checks for cancellation

Comment: @Christopher, I don't think I understand you clearly, can you show me some example ?...About multithreading in ExportData - without multithreading my xxport runs slowly - It's not just catching data from DB, but also designing Excel worksheet to drop data.

Comment: @BugFinder, fixing to just .Show() doesn't solve my problem. Doing my research got me to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382305/show-a-form-while-backgroundworker-is-running), but I can't get It working same.

Comment: @Lucy82 Ok so what bit didnt work using that link?

Comment: Move the BackgroundWorker into "process_form". Move the start of the BackgroundWorker into process_form.Shown Event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx Move the buttons that interact with the BackgroundWoker (like a Cancel one) to "process_form" as well. Have RunWorker Completes close the Dialog via process_form.Close(). (replace process_form with the Proper instance). You might not be able to define the Code via a Lambda anymore. But that is more a limitation of using BGW vs actuall full scale Multithreading

Comment: @BugFinder, same error as in 1st attempt.

Comment: does the alert form do anything?

Comment: @BugFinder, yes It opens, code for ExportData continues, but then It stops with error, and alert form isn't closed.

Comment: @Christopher, I moved BGW into process_form, but what to do next ? I called BGW.RunWorkerAsync(); in Shown_event, but that freezes my UI Thread.

Comment: im guessing because you only have a close shown in your code if cancelled and dowork wont be called again surely to do the cancel so its gone past that point.  You need the run completed.  When i asked if alert form did anything - i meant within the alert form..

Comment: @BugFinder, there is no code at all within alert form, It's a simple form with a gif and a label.text "data is loading".. I just want to show and hide form while Async method ExportData is running, and close form when It stops.  I also tried inserting my ExporData into Dowork event, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: in your code above v1 is the more practical manner however, somehow we are all missing a point somewhere and its hard to pinpoint it with the above.  Im guessing part of the problem is that the export is not responding to the cancel because its inprogress. or that the showing of the alert form is the issue.

Comment: "I called BGW.RunWorkerAsync(); in Shown_event, but that freezes my UI Thread" The only way you could maybe freeze your UI Thread by starting a BackgroudnWorker is by reporting progress (and writing it on the GUI) too often. You would simply swamp the UI Thread in Updates and those can be suprisingly costly. That is one reason ReportProgress is limited to Primitive Types, so you do not run the danger to use too complex outputs.

Comment: @Christopher, then tell me what I'm doing wrong. As told, I've set BGW in "process_form" (a.k.a. "alert" in code provided), then BGW.RunWorkerAsync(); in Shown_event. And that freezes my UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I dropped BGW and did following thing:

1. opened form "process_form" ("alert" instance);
2. wrapped ExportData in async and run It;
3. in ExportData, right before opening SaveFileDialog:

> ```
> this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
>    {
>       alert.Close();
>      SaveFileDialog save_export = new SaveFileDialog
>      {
>       //...
>      }
>     });
> ```

Looks like SaveFiledialog needs to be opened in another thread, and that was probably an issue in my case. Thanks for help !